# Specifying a property of an object to use in ItemsControl binding

Tags: silverlight, xaml, binding

In my example WP7 app I want to use the same data template to display fruit in all ItemsControl controls.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="fruitDetails" >
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Color}" />
    </StackPanel >
</DataTemplate>
```

For a list of fruit I can bind like this:

```
XAML: 
<ItemsControl Name="itemControls1" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource fruitDetails }" >

C#
ObservableCollection<Fruit> fruits = new ObservableCollection <Fruit>();
itemControls1.ItemSource = fruits;
```

But some of my lists have fruit as a property:

```
class CargoBox
{
    public int CargoBoxNumber { get; set; }
    public Fruit TypeOfFruit { get; set; }
}

ObservableCollection <CargoBox> boxes = new ObservableCollection <CargoBox>();
```

If I want to display the fruit using the same DataTemplate, how can I bind this list and specify the property "TypeOfFruit"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a content template:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding CargoBoxNumber}" />
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding TypeOfFruit}"  ContentTemplate="{StaticResource fruitDetails}" />
</StackPanel>
```